# NSManaged Core Data -

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an entity with an attribute `value` of type "Double". Why, when I create an NSManagedObject subclass for this does it change to an `NSNumber`?

```
@NSManaged var value: NSNumber
```

Thanks.

Comment: All numeric data types are (and have always been) bridged to `NSNumber`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With new version of Xcode you no longer can store have types of Integer, Double, Bool when creating a `NSManagedObject subclass`. They are all declared as `NSNumber`

You can convert them to double by calling `doubleValue` function:

```
let myDouble = value.doubleValue
```